# DICOM listener - take control of association actions

Tags: dicom, dcm4che

Trying to implement a DICOM Router desktop (Java) application using dcm4che (v.2) toolkit.

The DICOM Router should accept any incoming DICOM send requests, store the files locally (in a certain folder structure) and after each DICOM study send request completion it should process the files in a certain way (internal actions).

I am using the dcmrcv util/tool for implementing a DICOM receiver in the following way (getDcmRcv() is actually a dmcRcv object):

```
...
private final CustomStorageService storageSCP = new CustomStorageService(CUIDS);
...
public DcmRcv(String name) {
    device = new Device(name);
    executor = new NewThreadExecutor(name);

    device.setNetworkApplicationEntity(ae);
    device.setNetworkConnection(nc);
    ae.setNetworkConnection(nc);
    ae.setAssociationAcceptor(true);
    ae.register(new VerificationService());
    ae.register(storageSCP);
    ae.register(stgcmtSCP);        
    ae.addAssociationListener(storageSCP);
}
```

I have somehow modified StorageService to manage an AssociationListener in the following way:

```
private final class CustomStorageService extends StorageService implements AssociationListener {
    public CustomStorageService(final String[] sopClasses) {
        super(sopClasses);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCStoreRQ(final Association association, final int pcid, final DicomObject dcmReqObj,
                               final PDVInputStream dataStream, final String transferSyntaxUID,
                               final DicomObject dcmRspObj)
            throws DicomServiceException, IOException {

        final String classUID = dcmReqObj.getString(Tag.AffectedSOPClassUID);
        final String instanceUID = dcmReqObj.getString(Tag.AffectedSOPInstanceUID);

        GlobalConfig config = new GlobalConfig();
        final File associationDir = config.getAssocDirFile();

        final String prefixedFileName = instanceUID;
    final String dicomFileBaseName = prefixedFileName + DICOM_FILE_EXTENSION;

    File dicomFile = new File(associationDir, dicomFileBaseName + PARTIAL_FILE_EXTENSION);
    assert !dicomFile.exists();

    final BasicDicomObject fileMetaDcmObj = new BasicDicomObject();
    fileMetaDcmObj.initFileMetaInformation(classUID, instanceUID, transferSyntaxUID);

    final DicomOutputStream outStream = new DicomOutputStream(
        new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(dicomFile), 600000));
    try {
        outStream.writeFileMetaInformation(fileMetaDcmObj);
        dataStream.copyTo(outStream);

    } finally {
        outStream.close();
    }
        dicomFile.renameTo(new File(associationDir, dicomFileBaseName));
        System.out.println("DICOM file name: " + dicomFile.getName());
    }
}
```

In such way i can accept DICOM send requests from a client (e.g. Mayam) BUT the files are stored in a flat structure in directory "rootDirectory" (C:\XXXXXX\YYYY\Development\AssocDir).

I am trying to get information such as StudyID and SeriedID from the association object to create a folder structure like: root/StudyID/SeriesID/DicmFile from dcmReqObj or dicomFile ... However:

dcmReqObj is actually empty (only AffectedSOPClassUID & AffectedSOPInstanceUID tags are populated)

Even if i try to fetch it after: outStream.writeFileMetaInformation(fileMetaDcmObj) the StudyID tag is not yet populated (inside this method) ...

Also in this method if i try to fetch "dicomFile" inside onCStoreRQ  i can only take it in a transitional phase where it is not yet a populated DICOM object ...

What i have been missing here?

Comment: have you managed to figure it out? I'm in the same shoes, I'd like to retrieve data from dcm4chee into my java app (using dcm4che), so I send out a c-move to dcm4chee from my java app, but don't know how to set up an association listener to handle the incoming c-store request when dcm4chee wants to send me the data. Do you have some sample code to put me on the right track?

Comment: If i can recall well i have used the DcmRcv & StorageSCP classes to implement this dicom listener. For instance during my application initialization i am checking whether dicom receiver is running; if not i am starting it using: setAEtitle(), setHostname(), setPort() for defining your listener's "address" and then: setDestination() for defining where the incoming files are going to be stored, initTransferCapability() and finally start() to start the receiver. Check documentation and examples for DcmRcv class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do more than just use the DcmRcv class as is.

Use it as a starting point, but you'll also want to implement the

```
org.dcm4che2.net.AssociationListener
```

interface to intercept association requests, along with the

```
org.dcm4che2.net.service.StorageService
```

class for the actual data transfer.

Comment: Thanks alot for answering! Yeap that is what i was also thinking. But are there any examples or could you provide an abstract example of such kind of implementation? For example a question is how am i going to "attach" the association listener to the dcmrcv instance?

Comment: You can use the DcmRcv class as your model. Adding the AssociationListener interface is straight forward, then assign it to the AE using NetworkApplicationEntity.addAssociationListener(..)

Comment: Thanks for responding ... implemented like that and now i can monitor Association and C-STORE requests ... However all these association requests refer to independent DICOM file send requests. My DICOM client is sending whole studies! Is there any way to monitor when a whole study is sent? And then initiate a streamline of actions?

Comment: You should be able to key on the close association, IF the sender sends everything in one association. If they do not, contact the vendor and see if there is a good reason to send things in separate associations; there often is not and hopefully it can be configured to open an association, send everything, and then close the association.

Comment: I'll note that if they are required to send an association for each instance or series, then there really isn't a concrete way to determine when you have received the whole study just by the association or storage messages.

Comment: OK! thanks! at least how could i grab and process the individual dicom files after each association closure? I am trying to do so on the level of an "associationClosed" internal method but i can not really figure how! I have modified my question so as to reflect the point to which i am now!

Comment: You can get the study/series info from the onCStoreReq method to save where you need. It also provides the Association object so that you can match them up when you receive the associationClosed notification. Just keep track of what studies or file directories are associated with the association, then do you processing when it closes.

Comment: I am trying to get StudyID from "dcmReqObj" or "dicomFile" at the end of onCStoreRQ but the corresponding tag is empty! However if i check file system the dicom files are accepted and stored just fine! I have changed the question so as to depict the point to which i am now...

Comment: DicomObject object = dataStream.readDataset(); should get you the object stored. You're looking in the request or response object not the actual data.

Answer (score 1):

In your scenario, if the use of Java/Dcm4Che is not mandatory, you could take a look at [Orthanc](http://www.orthanc-server.com/) as a complement to Dcm4che to implement DICOM auto-routing. Orthanc is a lightweight, open-source DICOM server that provides scripting abilities: Examples of DICOM auto-routing through [Lua scripting](https://code.google.com/p/orthanc/source/browse/Resources/Samples/Lua/AutoroutingConditional.lua) or through [REST calls](https://code.google.com/p/orthanc/source/browse/Resources/Samples/Python/HighPerformanceAutoRouting.py) are available.

Comment: dcm4che is not mandatory however the DICOM router we are trying to build is a cross platform native application (JavaFX & dcm4chee). Does Orthanc support such kind of implementation?

Comment: Orthanc is cross-platform (Windows, Linux, OS X), and you can interact with it from any computer language (notably Java) through its RESTful API.